# Best and fastest way to place items on a Google map with PHP

Tags: php, google-maps

For the project I'm currently working on I have a database with locations (restaurants, hotels, coffee shops etc.) and I have to place each one on a map. For each location I have its name and full address. What is the best and fastest way to accomplish this using Google Maps? I'm using PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would send the JSON/XML object using javascript from the php to the GoogleMaps API.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Services_Overview